# Specify the table to import via IMPORTHTML/IMPORTXML according to its title name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The tables change position and I need to specify which one to import according to their title, for example, the table below has the title `Over/Under 2.5 soccer predictions`

**Site**:
https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/

[image]

**Unsuccessful attempts**:

1 - I tried to use `IMPORTXML` by specifying the table id, but the import results in all the data in one column, it does not import as a table:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
           "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gvOverUnderPredictions']//td")
```

2 - I tried to use `IMPORTHML` combined with `IMPORTXML` to define the title, but the result returns completely blank:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTHTML(A2,"table", VLOOKUP(A1, {
 TRIM(IMPORTXML(A2,"//h3[@id='1x2']")), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 TRIM(IMPORTXML(A2,"//h3[@id='1x2']")))))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

***The expected result would be like this:***
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
           "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gvOverUnderPredictions']/tbody/tr")
```

[image]