# Return column values from the column title

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In answer to my question (I will leave the link below), the formula being used and the result are as follows:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65451225/11462274

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
           "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gv1X2Predictions']/tbody/tr")
```

[image]

The columns can change position, but the title of each one follows the new column position, so how could I ask for a formula to search where the column with `title X` is and from that find the values of `⚽ Matches`

In this case, the value would be:
Explanation via VLOOKUP:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(B2:B),B1:F,3,FALSE)))
```

[image]

The problem with `VLOOKUP` is that the column with the `title X` may not always be in `column D` and `⚽ Matches` may not always be in `column B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(B2:B), 
  {FLATTEN(QUERY(TO_TEXT(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
  "https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
  "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gv1X2Predictions']/tbody/tr"))), 
  "where Col1 contains 'Matches'", 0)), IMPORTXML(
  "https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
  "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gv1X2Predictions']/tbody/tr")}, 5, 0)))
```

eg. the part is:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(QUERY(TO_TEXT(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
 "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gv1X2Predictions']/tbody/tr"))), 
 "where Col1 contains 'Matches'", 0))
```

and the full formula:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(B2:B), 
  {FLATTEN(QUERY(TO_TEXT(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
  "https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
  "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gv1X2Predictions']/tbody/tr"))), 
  "where Col1 contains 'Matches'", 0)), IMPORTXML(
  "https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
  "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gv1X2Predictions']/tbody/tr")}, 
  MATCH("X", INDEX(IMPORTXML(
  "https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
  "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gv1X2Predictions']/tbody/tr"), 1), 0)+1, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I had a doubt, because if by chance the column with heading ```X``` changes from the **fourth column** to the **third column**, the result would return wrong, there would be some way to define instead of ```4```, put the value column search like ```X```?

Comment: @BrondbyIF yes. answer updated. code: `MATCH("X", INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.soccerstats247.com/predictions/brazil/serie-a/",
 "//table[@id='soccerContentPlaceHolder_gv1X2Predictions']/tbody/tr"), 1), 0)`